# e-ink display for raspberry

Tags: display, connection

I would like to display some actual temperatures, humidities, time and maybe some graph permanently on the wall. Does there exist some larger (like 12'') e-ink display for RPi?

Comment: Older (pre 2014) model Kindles can be made to act as wifi enabled e-ink screens. http://mpetroff.net/2012/09/kindle-weather-display/ Unfortunately my Kindle is a 2014 model and cannot be rooted :(

Comment: I know it's not at the size you want but there's a Kickstarter for a small HAT-sized one at the moment. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1372954669/e-paper-display-hat-for-the-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All large e-ink displays I have seen were a mosaic of small displays. Manufacturers make medium to small book sized displays for [example](http://www.eink.com/display_products_carta.html) 13.3". Though it may be cheaper to get the parts from an existing consumer product if you plan a volume of one.

You can hook pretty much anything to the rpi but sometimes the work has [already](http://maxogden.com/kindleberry-wireless.html) been done.

The largest ereader I know of is 10.2" and 10X the price of a 1080p 24" led monitor, so unless you are on solar it's economy a few years early for large e-ink.

Comment: Manufacturer does not tell the price and could be a question how ot connect.....The kindle solution you refer is **nice**, but has one big difficulty. My experience is, that playing with firmware is doable, but finally you may invest a lot of time and effort to - just a display. Thanks